# Remove all but 2 objects from array with specific property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove objects from an array based on a property - but want to save two of them

```
var arr = [{"name": "John", "class": "warrior"},
 {"name": "Jane", "class": "mage"},
 {"name": "Doug", "class": "monk"},
 {"name": "Danna", "class": "warrior"}, ..]

var new_arr = arr.filter(function(el) { return el.class !== "warrior"; });

   // new_arr == [{"name": "Jane", "class": "mage"},
   //  {"name": "Doug", "class": "monk"}, ...]
```

How can I do this if I want to remove or keep a specific number of those objects - like remove all but two objects with `class == "warrior"`

Comment: Use `slice` to truncate array length to 2: `var new_arr = arr.filter(function(el) { return el.class == "warrior"; }).slice(0, 2);`

Comment: @hindmost and then re-add it to the original array?

Comment: @maximl337, why do you want to add something you've just filtered from an array back into that same array?

Comment: @hindmost Well - I was wondering if there is a way to remove specific number of objects ( or leave specific number ) based on their property. if you look at my question - var new_arr = arr.filter(function(el) { return el.class !== "warrior"; }); //removes all warrior class objects.  your solution creates an array with the 2 of the require objects - so i would have to re-add it to the original array.

Comment: @maximl337 Just replace `new_arr` with `arr`: `var arr = arr.filter(function(el) { return el.class == "warrior"; }).slice(0, 2);`

Comment: I think (hope) the requirement is to keep all mages, monks, etc.. , remove all the warriors, _but_ keep 2 warriors in the array. So you end up with e.g. 5 mages, 8 monks and __2 warriors__.

Comment: @Rhumborl Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind which ones get removed, you can skip returning `false` for the first 2 warriors in your filter. You just need a variable to keep track of how many warriors you have matched and increment it when you find one:

So for John and Danna, `matched` will be 1 and 2 respectively and so kept in the array:

```
var arr = [
    { "name": "John", "class": "warrior" },
    { "name": "Jane", "class": "mage" },
    { "name": "Doug", "class": "monk" },
    { "name": "Danna", "class": "warrior"},
    { "name": "Bob", "class": "warrior" },
    { "name": "Someone", "class": "mage" },
    { "name": "Bob2", "class": "warrior" },
    { "name": "Bob3", "class": "warrior" },
    { "name": "Bob4", "class": "warrior" }
];

var matched = 0;
var new_arr = arr.filter(function (el) {
    return (el.class !== "warrior" || ++matched <= 2);
});
```

Comment: ah yes i get it. ill try it out.